# Nginx and rewrite rule redirection from html

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect, nginx, server

I've got problem with making rewrite rule in nginx and i need your help. How to make rewrite rule from http://www.example.com/2015/03/link-to-page.html to http://www.example.com/link-to-page/ 
I've tried this

```
location / {
rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)\.html?$" /$1/ redirect;
}
```

but it's not working. 
Thank you

Comment: Are you asking how to enable/change wordpress' permalink structure?

Comment: I need rewrite rule to redirect old links from blogspot to wordpress

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you are matching the entire url. The "^" at the beginning is the start of the string, not the exclude character.

```
rewrite "^/\d{4}/\d{2}/(?<domain>.+)$"  http://$host/$domain permanent;
```

The domain variable is regex name. It can be anything.

Comment: Hello, it's not working please give me good example with location which i gave you i my question tab. Thank You

Comment: I edited the answer. Since there are {} I needed to add quotes. I also changed the regex to use the '\d' and change the redirect to permanent. I don't think you actually need the "http://$host" part in the redirect.